# What is the easiest way to solve the following constrained optimization problem in python?

Tags: python, optimization, constrained-optimization

So, I have a simple optimization problem, I have a cloud of 3D points, $x = (x_1, x_2\dots x_n) $ with $x_i = [x_{i1}, x_{i2}, x_{i3}]$. And I want to minimize the mean squared error between the original cloud of points $x$ and the result of a transformation applied to these points $f(x),  \text{min mse}(x, f(x))$. Respecting some constraints (ex: $x_1 = x_2, \text{dist}(x_2,x_3) < c$, etc).

What is the simplest way to solve that in python? Is there any package that solves such problem easily?

Comment: If f is convex, see https://www.cvxpy.org/